# Find all value of a that series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find all $\alpha$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \ln \Big( \sinh {\frac{1}{n} }\Big)  - \ln{\frac{1}{n}} \Big)^{\alpha}$ is covergent
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \ln \Big( \sinh{\frac{1}{n} }\Big)  - \ln{\frac{1}{n}} \Big)^{\alpha} = 
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \ln \Big( n\sinh{\frac{1}{n} }\Big)\Big)^{\alpha} = 
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \ln \Big( n  \big( \frac{1}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})  \big) \Big)\Big)^{\alpha}  =
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \ln \Big(  1 + o(1) \Big) \Big)^{\alpha} =
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( o(1) + o(o(1)) \Big)^{\alpha} $$

If I did the right things, how to go on? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to be more precise than $\sinh x = x + o(x)$. Take a higher order Taylor polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is an excellent start.  Then I would be a little more precise in the next step, by expanding $\ln\left( n \sinh \frac1n \right)$ as a series in $\frac1n$:
$$\ln\left( n \sinh \frac1n \right) = \frac1{6n^2}-\frac1{180n^4} +O(\frac1{n^6})
$$
So each term is positive and smaller than $\frac1{6n^2}$

Now you are raising each term to the power $\alpha$, so if $\alpha>\frac12$ the series is smaller, term by term, than  $$\sum\frac1{6n^{1+(\frac12-\frac\alpha2)}}$$ which converges.  If $\alpha = \frac12$ it turns out that the series diverges because the $\frac1{n^4}$ terms themselves converge, leaving the harmonic series.

So the answer is that your sum converges for $\alpha > \frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let
$$f(x)=\ln(\sinh(x))-\ln x$$
and write $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)+\frac12f''(0)x^2+o(x^2)$. You will get the anwser.